# countplot from several columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe with several categorical columns. I know how to do countplot which routinly plots ONE column.
Q: how to plot maximum count from ALL columns in one plot?

here is an exemplary dataframe to clarify the question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

testdf=pd.DataFrame(({   'Ahome' :   pd.Categorical(["home"]*10),
                         'Bsearch' : pd.Categorical(["search"]*8 + ["NO"]*2),
                          'Cbuy' : pd.Categorical(["buy"]*5 + ["NO"]*5),
                          'Dcheck' : pd.Categorical(["check"]*3 + ["NO"]*7),
                      
                     
                     } ))
testdf.head(10)
sns.countplot(data=testdf,x='Bsearch');
```

The last line is just using normal countplot for one column. I'd like to have the columns category (home,search,buy and check) in x-axis and their frequency in y-axis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `countplot` as below:

```
df = pd.melt(testdf)
sns.countplot(data=df.loc[df['value']!="NO"], x='variable', hue='value')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! any idea how can I remove the "NO" from values?

Comment: What do you mean by removing "NO" from values?

Comment: I mean show everything as it is in your plot, except NO values for each column.

Comment: superb! Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help. @physiker

Answer (score 4):

As @HarvIpan points out, using `melt` you would create a long-form dataframe with the column names as entries. Calling `countplot` on this dataframe produces the correct plot.

As a difference to the existing solution, I would recommend not to use the `hue` argument at all.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(({   'Ahome' :   pd.Categorical(["home"]*10),
                         'Bsearch' : pd.Categorical(["search"]*8 + ["NO"]*2),
                          'Cbuy' : pd.Categorical(["buy"]*5 + ["NO"]*5),
                          'Dcheck' : pd.Categorical(["check"]*3 + ["NO"]*7),


                     } ))

df2 = df.melt(value_vars=df.columns)
df2 = df2[df2["value"] != "NO"]
sns.countplot(data=df2, x="variable")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks also very good! Could you please just edit your answer because now I guess there are some mismatching between your example data and your plot (which is correct). Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry. That was such a stupid mistake (I copied the code from a completely different editor tab.) Should now be fixed.

Comment: Great job, thanks! this is also en excellent solution as well and works somehow faster on my real dataframe which is large.

Comment: hi, I'm commenting in this answer as my question is very related. I'm wondering how you could do to show the proportions of each category together with "NO". For instance, for `Dcheck` it would show the bottom 1/3 as `check`, the top 2/3 as `NO`. Is this possible? As it stands, without excluding `NO`, `countplot` just counts the number of rows per column of the original df